# how to replace a macro with a string?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#define ammo "full"

int main()
{
  char a[100];
  a = ammo;
  printf("%s",a);
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to replace `#define ammo` with `"full"` (string) and want to print it on the screen to check if it works but the code is not compiling.

Comment: `a=ammo` --> `strcpy()`

Comment: or `char *a = ammo;`

Comment: or `char a[100] = ammo;` just to complete the set.

Comment: Now, [pick up a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This is among the basic things one learns when starting.

Comment: how *a=ammo works?

Comment: the macro is replaced by a string by the _pre-processor_. What you are actually want is to assign that string to `a`

Comment: `*a=ammo` does not work. What Filip mentioned was `char *a = ammo;` which is totally different as it is definition with initialization instead of an assignment.

Comment: @karan - No, `*a=ammo` doesn't work because `a` is an array and not a pointer. *Please* read a book, it works much faster than trial-and-error.

Comment: @karanshaarma Because a string is essentially a **sequence of characters**. A pointer can represent it by pointing to the 1st character.

Comment: For all the bitter SO veterans who've been reading this without casting close votes, check out the C FAQ below the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info). It contains many useful canonical duplicates, including "How do I copy strings?" and "How do I compare strings?".

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a=ammo; you should use strcpy(a,ammo); you should not use a direct assignment when you have strings, but use the C method strcpy to copy a string to another.  it will work

Comment: For a better answer, I think you should add the 2 other options provided by StoryTeller and Filip Kočica :)

Answer (score 2):

It's invalid to assign a C-string to an array (except when initializing, see below). You must "copy" the string to the array because the space is already allocated:

```
strcpy(a, ammo);
```

Better yet, use a safer version of copy function:

```
strncpy(a, ammo, sizeof(a) / sizeof(char));
```

Or directly assign it when initializing:

```
char a[100] = ammo;
```

Or, don't use array. Use a pointer instead:

```
char *a;
a = ammo;
```

Note you can't change the content of the string if you use a pointer.